# Usage of "paprika" and "bell pepper"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I heard a native speaker of American English talking about *paprika*, and I was irritated because I only knew the term *bell pepper* as the translation for this vegetable.

Differences like *peppercorn* or *chili pepper* are clear and already answered sufficiently well:

- [How can I differentiate peppers?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/how-can-i-differentiate-peppers)
- [(Bell pepper, capsicum, chilli, pepper) What's the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170623/bell-pepper-capsicum-chilli-pepper-whats-the-difference)
- [Does 'pepper' include bell peppers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38864/does-pepper-include-bell-peppers)

So will *paprika* be used

- to specify the spice (dried and ground bell pepper)?
- in specific regions?
- only in a cooking jargon?
- as a synonym to *bell pepper*?

Comment: What did https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paprika not answer?

Answer (score 2):

Paprika is a spice made by drying and powdering certain varieties of bell pepper.

The name is used widely in the English speaking world.

As paprika is a spice, the word will be mainly used in a food context.

Paprika is not a synonym for "bell pepper" in English.

[Paprika](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paprika)